# Regex expression for a chosen file name format

Tags: c#, regex

I am want to implement some regex to test a valid filename as:
ABCD-A-V1-02/27/2012

Where the first letter should not be more than 4 letters, the second group goes from A-to-Z and the V# like V1, V2, etc

Here is what I have until now, but in the reg tester does not work, I think I a missing something.

```
[a-zA-Z]{4}-[A-Z]{1}-V\d{0,9}[1-9])|(0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))\/(([0-9])|([0-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\/(([0-9][0-9])|([1-2][0,9][0-9][0-9]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also you can put `^...$` sign for just validate your desire pattern exactly

```
 @"^[a-zA-Z]{1,4}-[A-Z]-V\d-\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}$"
```

it will just validate only your desire pattern , rest of all is invalid

valid : AAAa-aa-v232-12/12/2-2010
invlid: AAAa-aa-v232-12/12/2-20103343AAAA

Answer (score 2):

Here's the problems I see based on [your description](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9459928/1):

- The quantifier for the first group of alphabetic characters is requiring exactly four characters instead of up to four characters
- The pattern doesn't contain the second group of alphabetic character(s) (`'A'`)
- The pattern doesn't contain the forward slashes for the date.
- You've got some things going on inside of curly brackets that aren't valid

Try this:

```
@"[a-zA-Z]{1,4}-[A-Z]-V\d-\d{2}/\d{2}/\d{4}"
```

That breaks down as:

- At least one and no more than four alphabetic characters, case-insensitive
- A hyphen
- A single uppercase alphabetic character
- A hyphen
- An uppercase `'V'`
- A single digit
- A hyphen
- Two digits
- A forward slash
- Two digits
- A forward slash
- Four digits

Obviously this won't ensure that the digits at the end represent a valid date.

Comment: Thanks, that was a simple solution!